# Error creating table in SQL Server with IF

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a proc:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure create_table_test, Line 11
>   There is already an object named '#tmp' in the database.

The procedure is creating a temp table based on an `IF` statement but SQL Server doesn't recognize the create table statements are inside an IF and only one will be executed. Any "clean" way around this?

```
create procedure [dbo].[create_table_test]
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    if 1=1
        create table #tmp (field1 int)
    else
        create table #tmp (field1 varchar(10))
end
```

Comment: The table structures are different, so how about using a different name for the  2nd temp table?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use a global temp table, then you can farm out the creation of the table to two procs. This way the SQL Parser won't get confused.

```
create procedure [dbo].[create_tmpint]
AS
BEGIN

    set nocount on
    create table ##tmp (field1 int)

end
go


drop procedure create_tmpvar
go
create procedure [dbo].[create_tmpvar]
AS
BEGIN

    set nocount on
    create table ##tmp (field1 varchar(10))

end
go

drop procedure create_table_test
go
create procedure [dbo].[create_table_test]
AS
BEGIN

    set nocount on

    if 1=1 begin
        exec [dbo].[create_tmpint]  
    end    
    else 
        exec [dbo].[create_tmpvar]  


    insert into ##tmp values(1)

    select * from ##tmp

end
go
```

If you run `exec [dbo].[create_table_test]` you will get the value 1 returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (tempColumn int)

IF 1=1
    ALTER TABLE #tmp ADD field1 int
ELSE
    ALTER TABLE #tmp ADD field1 varchar(10)

ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN tempColumn
```